# Citrix-XenApp Error (SSL-Server 61) with FF on OpenSuse 12.2: how to bypass?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, opensuse, citrix

good day dear Superuser,

I am trying to utilize Citrix XenApp to remotely access my work
userid and applications from home. I can login and see my virtual
desktop/applications, but when I try to run an application
I get

> SSL Error 61: you have chosen not to trust "Thawte Premium Server CA"

the issuer of the server's security certificate.

How to get rid this error?
What can i do!?

How can i try to to update the certificate with FF

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the application needs to trust the "Thawte Premium Server CA" certificate which is a root certificate. It could mean that the SSL certificate was not installed correctly on the application, resulting in this error. With Thawte's SSL certificate, you must make sure that the intermediate certificates along with the SSL certificate are installed correctly on the application/server.